# Degree distribution of Barabasi-Albert model

Tags: python, ubuntu, networkx

I have a been able to run the run this:

```py
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 20
m = 3

G_barabasi = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n,m)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
nx.draw(G_barabasi, node_size=4)
plt.show()
```

The above code was able to plot the nodes and edges.

However, I need to obtain the degree of distribution of the Barabasi-Albert Model or rather the power-law degree distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could make use of [`nx.degree_histogram`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.degree_histogram.html), which returns a list of frequencies of the degrees in the network, where the degree values are the corresponding indices in the list.

Normally the logarithm of both `x` and `y` axes is taken when plotting the degree distribution, this helps seing if a networkx is [scale-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network) (a network whose degree distribution follows a power law) which is the case with the [Barabási–Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model), we can use [`plt.loglog`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.loglog.html) for that:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2000
m = 3
G_barabasi = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n,m)

degree_freq = nx.degree_histogram(G_barabasi)
degrees = range(len(degree_freq))
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8)) 
plt.loglog(degrees[m:], degree_freq[m:],'go-') 
plt.xlabel('Degree')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response. I had run code while studying earlier, however, this output wasn't too good for me because I could not remove the lines. here is the code: degree_freq = np.array(nx.degree_histogram(G_barabasi)).astype('float')
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.stem(degree_freq, use_line_collection=True)
plt.ylabel("Frequence")
plt.xlabel("Degree")
#use_line_collection" keyword argument to True
plt.show().     How do I remove the lines, because I see that the lines(vertical) aint there in yours. Hope to get answer. Thanks

Comment: Updated using `degree_histogram` too @jimi

Comment: Thanks, @yatu for the response.** But how do I obtain the log-log plot for this algorithm. Tried all I can but didn't get any headway. I will appreciate your response.**

Comment: Note that I'm using plt.loglog,this takes the log of both axes @jimi